# how to get the value of category and then displays it in another textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value "111" from the category from the option tag in the 'second_dropdown' list and display it in another input tag, I am new in javascript. I hope you guys get what I am trying to achieve.

here is my code but its not what I am trying to achieve:

Source:

```
 <select id="first_dropdown" type="text" name="department" required>
   <option value="">Select Department</option>
   <option id="111" value="Finance Department">Finance Department</option>
 </select>


<select id="second_dropdown" type="text" name="position" required>
   <option value="">Select Position</option>
   <option category="111" value="Finance Director">Finance Director</option>
</select>
```

Output:

```
<input id="result" type="text" name="xyz" onblur="get_value()">
```

Script:

```
function get_value() {
    var result;
    result=document.getElementById('second_dropdown').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value=result;
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing this for learning, great! If not, jQuery makes this easier - but it's easy to end up with a site that's hard to maintain. You might want to look at lightweight frameworks like React.

Comment: Do you have a sample code sir on how will you get the value from the category, and maybe I could use it

Comment: it's not about solving your current issue with a drop-in fix, it's about rearchitecting your entire site for long-term maintainability. You could start here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I get what you are trying to say to me sir and I found a code for maintaining the page recently sir, I was trying to get the value "111" from the category and store it in database sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an example:**

You can track changes by [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and every time user enter an input you can take that input and do whatever you want.

I recommend you to check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) out!

```js
const secDrop = document.getElementById('second_dropdown');
const res = document.getElementById('result');

secDrop.addEventListener('change', e => {
    res.value = e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('category');
    // this is the category value
    console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('category'));
});
```

```html
<select id="first_dropdown" type="text" name="department" required>
   <option value="">Select Department</option>
   <option id="111" value="Finance Department">Finance Department</option>
 </select>


<select id="second_dropdown" type="text" name="position" required>
   <option value="">Select Position</option>
   <option category="111" value="Finance Director">Finance Director</option>
</select>

<input id="result" type="text" name="xyz">
```

Comment: You have point sir but what I am trying to achieve is how to get the category value sir so I can use the value from the category and store it on database

Comment: `e.target.value` is the value you want.

Comment: I want to get the value of category="111" and store it in database sir

Comment: i updated my answer, look out. `e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('category')` this piece gives you the `category` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectedOptions and selectedIndex to get the value you need.

Check out the code snippets here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement